Pygame saying video system not initialized
I'm new to pygame and I've being trying to make a Wordle game. This function in particular is faulty, I think it is because I'm using while true loops its saying the video system is not initialized for (pygame.display.update() and pygame.event.get()) but I don't know how to get around this.
def playgame():
    global t_score 
    global play
    screen.fill("White")
    row = []
    newgame = Word()
    screen.blit(header,header_rec)
    newgame = getgame()    
    row.append(Box(100,100,120,space_)) 
    row.append(Box(100,100,260,space_)) 
    row.append(Box(100,100,400,space_)) 

    row[0].makerow()
    row[1].makerow()
    row[2].makerow()

    meaning_text = font_meaning.render(f'Meaning: {newgame.meaning}',True,"Black")
    meaning_rec = meaning_text.get_rect(center=(325,576))
    screen.blit(meaning_text,meaning_rec)
    screen.blit(keyboard,keyboard_rec)
    score_text = font_score.render(f'Total score: {t_score}',False,"Black")
    score_text_rec = score_text.get_rect(center=(35,19))
    screen.blit(score_text,score_text_rec)
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            play = False
            pygame.quit()

    win = 0
    score = 8 
    for attempts in range (0,3):
        word_guess = [" "]*5
        for letter_count in range (0,5):
            letter = ' '
            run = True
            while run:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        run = False
                        pygame.quit()
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: 
                        if(a_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'A'
                        if(b_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'B'
                        if(c_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'C'
                        if(d_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'D'
                        if(e_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'E'
                        if(f_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'F'     
                        if(g_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'G'
                        if(h_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'H'  
                        if(i_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'I'
                        if(j_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'J'
                        if(k_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'K'   
                        if(l_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'L' 
                        if(m_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'M'
                        if(n_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'N'
                        if(o_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'O'   
                        if(p_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'P'
                        if(q_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'Q'
                        if(r_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'R'
                        if(s_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'S'
                        if(t_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'T'   
                        if(u_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'U'   
                        if(v_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'V'
                        if(w_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'W'
                        if(x_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'X'
                        if(y_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'Y' 
                        if(z_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = 'Z'

                        if(letter != " "):
                            letter_print = font_letter.render(f'{letter}',True,"Black")
                            letter_rec = letter_print.get_rect(center=(row[attempts].box_surface_rect[letter_count].center))
                            screen.blit(letter_print,letter_rec)
                            pygame.display.update()
                        
                        if(letter != " " and delete_kb_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            letter = " "
                            row[attempts].surface_.fill("White")
                            screen.blit(row[attempts].surface_,row[attempts].box_surface_rect[letter_count])
                            pygame.draw.rect(screen,"Black",row[attempts].box_surface_rect[letter_count],1)
                            pygame.display.update()
                        

                            

                        if(letter != " " and enter_kb_rec.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
                            if(letter == newgame.word[letter_count]):
                                row[attempts].surface_.fill("Green")
                                screen.blit(row[attempts].surface_,row[attempts].box_surface_rect[letter_count])
                                pygame.draw.rect(screen,"Black",row[attempts].box_surface_rect[letter_count],1)
                                screen.blit(letter_print,letter_rec)
                                pygame.display.update()
                                run = False
                            elif(letter in newgame.word):
                                row[attempts].surface_.fill("Orange")
                                screen.blit(row[attempts].surface_,row[attempts].box_surface_rect[letter_count])
                                pygame.draw.rect(screen,"Black",row[attempts].box_surface_rect[letter_count],1)
                                screen.blit(letter_print,letter_rec)
                                pygame.display.update()
                                run = False
                            else:
                                row[attempts].surface_.fill("Red")
                                screen.blit(row[attempts].surface_,row[attempts].box_surface_rect[letter_count])
                                pygame.draw.rect(screen,"Black",row[attempts].box_surface_rect[letter_count],1)
                                screen.blit(letter_print,letter_rec)
                                pygame.display.update()
                                run = False
            word_guess[letter_count] = letter
        guess = ''.join(word_guess)
        if(guess == newgame.word):
            win  = 1
            t_score += score
            start = True
            while start:
                congrats = font_smaller.render(f'Word was: {newgame.word} Press Enter to start new game',False,"Black")
                congrats_rect = pygame.Rect(91,678,586,24)
                screen.blit(congrats,congrats_rect)
                pygame.display.update()
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        start = False
                        pygame.quit()
                    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                            start = False
                            playgame()
                            
            pygame.display.update()
        else:
            score -= 1

    if(win == 0):
        start = True
        while start:
            congrats = font_smaller.render(f'Word was: {newgame.word} Press Enter to start new game',False,"Black")
            congrats_rect = pygame.Rect(91,678,586,24)
            screen.blit(congrats,congrats_rect)
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        start = False
                        pygame.quit()
                    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                            start = False
                            playgame()
                            
    pygame.display.update()

This function should show the header and the keyboard, which worked perfectly before adding the if statements, now it is stuck on the home page. The function should also loop until a letter is entered, this is the the same for the 4 other letters. There are also three attempts for each word. After the attempts are done or if the guess is correct it should be intentionally stuck on the same window showing a congratulating message or a sorry message and asking if the user wants to play another game by hitting enter.
The error
enter image description here

Some tips for quick start in pygame:

Read the documentation very carefully! Reading it allows you to suck the marrow of it.

I think your enemy here is while True loop. It runs continuedly and the codes on the next lines are not run. Your pygame.display.update() is not inside the while loop. Refactor your code, follow the example below
https://pygame-gui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html

Thx. I repositioned the pygame.display.update()’s and its working perfectly now.

pygame must be initialized before you can use it.
Make sure you're using:
pygame.init()

at the start of your code.

thx for your response. It is at the beginning of the code but its giving the same error
